# How to correct a merge in wrong branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I merged the Branch `add-button` in master instead to merge it in `dev` branch !

My question is, how to undo this merge and make master branch like before, then merge add-button to dev branch ?

Comment: did you push to origin? Generally revert is the safest way to fix a bad commit, in that it writes only forward-moving history and can be safely pushed to origin, since it won't orphan other users copies of the branch. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert if you haven't pushed to origin you can use reset, which undoes a given commit, but it can be dangerous in some circumstances, and often origin is configured to prevent the rewriting of history.

Comment: if you haven't pushed, try checking out master and `git reset --hard origin/master`. if you have pushed, `git revert -m # <Commit hash>` where the # is the master parent of the merge (I know, thats  confusing). run git log and find the merge commit. its parents will be listed in order, so use the position it appears in the list. or if you use sourcetree, the parent commits will be listed if you select the merge commit.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes I pushed already

Comment: you will have to use `git revert` then. can you show us the output of `git log`? we only need to see the last few commits.